# Knowing which child have been changed from inside `onDataChange` Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Firebase Database structure

```
"randomParentID" : {
  "description" : "my description is here",
  "meetings" : {
    "randomidmeetings2" : true
  },
  "members" : {
    "WoZ3X4OZBuRepEuZZ0mUONa5h1a2" : true,
    "fjshtY3lFdWott5Zd6lr9rJSy7z1" : true
  },
  "title" : "my title"
}
```

I need to know when any value inside `randomParentID` is changed. So I placed `addValueEventListener` there.

But I also want to add `addChildEventListener` into `meetings` and `members` node to know more specific which data is added or removed.

With that, when I only want `onChildAdded` (or removed or changed) to be called, I will also get `onDataChange` (from listener of `randomParentID`) get called.

My question is, is there any way to know which of the children node that has been changed from inside `onDataChange` so that I can skip it when the data that been changed is `meetings` or `members`. event altogether. Thanks

Comment: why do you want to know if any value inside `randomParentID` is changed? is that because the `title` or `description` can be changed? or because you just want to listen for `members` update?

Comment: Yes, I want to know when title or description is changed. But I need `addChildEventValueListener` for `members` and `meetings` because those two have their own `RecyclerView`, so with that, I can beautifully animate the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way to know which of the children node that has been
>   changed from inside onDataChange

No, there isn't. Any small changes will always call `onDataChange`

You can instead attach ValueEventListener at `randomParentID/description` and `randomParentID/title` and keep using ChildEventListener at `randomParentID/meetings` and `randomParentID/members`

Or, move the `members` and `meetings` inside the object to outside of the item. The database will look like this

```
{
    "items" : {
        "randomParentID" : {
            "description" : "my description is here",
            "title" : "my title"
        }
    },
    "items_meetings" : {
        "randomParentID" : {
            "randomidmeetings2" : true
        }
    },
    "items_members" : {
        "randomParentID" : {
            "WoZ3X4OZBuRepEuZZ0mUONa5h1a2" : true,
            "fjshtY3lFdWott5Zd6lr9rJSy7z1" : true
        }
    }
}
```

With this structure, you can keep using `ValueEventListener` at `items/randomParentID`

Comment: Oh yes, why didn't I think of splitting the database. Thanks a lot